# SIGABRT inside fgets

Tags: c, linux

I have a relatively simple program that runs a bunch of shell scripts, concatenates their output into one string and sets it as statusbar for my display manager. For the most part everything is working
fine, but from time to time it crashes for no apart reason. Have inspected the coredump I found the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007fda71dc3d22 raise (libc.so.6 + 0x3cd22)
#1  0x00007fda71dad862 abort (libc.so.6 + 0x26862)
#2  0x00007fda71e05d28 __libc_message (libc.so.6 + 0x7ed28)
#3  0x00007fda71e0d92a malloc_printerr (libc.so.6 + 0x8692a)
#4  0x00007fda71e1109c _int_malloc (libc.so.6 + 0x8a09c)
#5  0x00007fda71e12397 malloc (libc.so.6 + 0x8b397)
#6  0x00007fda71dfb564 _IO_file_doallocate (libc.so.6 + 0x74564)
#7  0x00007fda71e09db0 _IO_doallocbuf (libc.so.6 + 0x82db0)
#8  0x00007fda71e08cbc _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (libc.so.6 + 0x81cbc)
#9  0x00007fda71e09e66 _IO_default_uflow (libc.so.6 + 0x82e66)
#10 0x00007fda71dfcf2c _IO_getline_info (libc.so.6 + 0x75f2c)
#11 0x00007fda71dfbe8a _IO_fgets (libc.so.6 + 0x74e8a)
#12 0x0000564c2b290484 getcmd (dwmblocks + 0x1484)
#13 0x0000564c2b2906ab getsigcmds (dwmblocks + 0x16ab)
#14 0x0000564c2b290b6f sighandler (dwmblocks + 0x1b6f)
#15 0x00007fda71dc3da0 __restore_rt (libc.so.6 + 0x3cda0)
#16 0x00007fda71e112cc _int_malloc (libc.so.6 + 0x8a2cc)
#17 0x00007fda71e13175 __libc_calloc (libc.so.6 + 0x8c175)
#18 0x00007fda71f83d23 XOpenDisplay (libX11.so.6 + 0x30d23)
#19 0x0000564c2b290952 setroot (dwmblocks + 0x1952)
#20 0x0000564c2b290b1a statusloop (dwmblocks + 0x1b1a)
#21 0x0000564c2b290e28 main (dwmblocks + 0x1e28)
#22 0x00007fda71daeb25 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x27b25)
#23 0x0000564c2b29020e _start (dwmblocks + 0x120e)
```

The last function of the program which has been run before crash looks something like this:

```
void getcmd(const Block *block, char *output)
{
...
    char *cmd = block->command;
    FILE *cmdf = popen(cmd,"r");
    if (!cmdf){
        return;
    }
    char tmpstr[CMDLENGTH] = "";
    char *s;
    int e;
    do {
        errno = 0;
        s = fgets(tmpstr, CMDLENGTH-(strlen(delim)+1), cmdf);
        e = errno;
    } while (!s && e == EINTR);
    pclose(cmdf);
...
}
```

So it's just calling popen and trying to read the output with fgets.

From the backtrace it is apparent that SIGABRT is generated inside the fgets call. I have two questions:

- How is it even possible? Isn't fgets has to return a string or an error if anything went wrong and let me deal with that error instead of bringing the whole program down?
- What should I do to prevent that behavior?

UPDATE:
Inspecting strings from coredump I found out that error which `malloc_printerr` was trying to report was `malloc(): mismatching next->prev_size (unsorted)`.
Don't know if it means anything...

UPDATE:
It appears the problem is that `getcmd` is called from signal handler, but `popen` and `fgets` is not signal-safe.

UPDATE:
I've added `setvbuf(cmdf, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` after `popen` call to make stream unbuffered so `fgets` wouldn't try to allocate buffers with `malloc` and hopefully prevent that crash. Unfortunately, I can't reliably reproduce the crash, so I can't tell if this hack helps.

Comment: `fgets()` is calling `malloc()`, and that's trying to report an error. I suspect that you have some undefined behavior earlier in the program, and it corrupted the heap, causing malloc to fail.

Comment: heap is trashed, time to break out valgrind (if you can)

Comment: `s = fgets(tmpstr, CMDLENGTH-(strlen(delim)+1), cmdf);` WHAT is `delim` ?

Comment: Looks like you've already got heap corruption when you call this function. You open the input, and the first time you read from it a buffer is `malloc()`ed. When `malloc()` tries to reserve the buffer, it finds the heap corruption and decides that your program should stop hurting itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So I basically can't tell from that coredump where the problem was?

Comment: @wildplasser delim is just static char *delim = " ";

Comment: *So I basically can't tell from that coredump where the problem was?*  Nope.  Whatever corrupted the heap laid a land mine or two - or more.  All you're seeing is the code that happened to step on one of those mines.  You need to find the bad code that laid them.

Comment: It looks like you're calling this function in a signal handler, which executes while the non-signal code is currently doing a `malloc()` already. Notably, `malloc()` is not signal-safe, so calling `malloc()` from a sigal handler (or transitively from a function called in a signal handler) is undefined behavior.

Comment: valgrind will find it for you

Comment: @EOF Thank you for great insight, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, I can see calls to malloc *twice* with a signal handler between them.  This is going to fail becuase malloc is (generally) not reentrant, so trying to call it from a signal handler is never a good idea.  In general, you should not call *ANY* POSIX async-unsafe function in a signal handler unless you can somehow guarentee that the signal will never be delivered while running any other async-unsafe function<sup>1</sup>.

So the real question here is why does your signal need to call popen or fgets (both async-unsafe) and what can you do about it?  What is the signal being caught?  Is it likely to be fatal anyways (SIGSEGV or SIGBUS), or is it an informational signal like SIGIO?

If it is a fatal signal, you should be looking into why it is occurring; the failure in the signal handler is secondary.

If it is a non-fatal signal, then you should move the async-unsafe code out of the signal handler and have the signal handler either set some global variable that the main program will check, or arrange for another thread to do whatever work is needed

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is possible but quite hard -- generally requires wrapping sigblock calls around all calls to async unsafe things.  However, if you only have a few of those in your main program, it may be practical.</sub>

Comment: It's SIGUSR signals. Program is reacting to them to make it possible to send signals to redraw different parts of statusbar. You are right, the proper way to do that should be to just set some flag in signal handler and do that job in another thread.

Comment: So you're calling fgets() and popen() *FROM INSIDE OF A SIGNAL HANDLER*?!?   From inside of a *DIFFERENT* instance of some other popen()??? Doh!

Comment: @paulsm4 `fgets` and `popen` from signal handler - yes, but not from different instance of popen.

Answer (score 0):

- Your code is calling [popen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to run some arbitrary Linux command.
- The "arbitrary command" is calling [XOpenDisplay()](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XOpenDisplay.3.html) to display an X Windows GUI to the user.
- The crash is occurring in [malloc()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html), deep inside XOpenDisplay.  Many other C library functions also use malloc() - including popen().
- THEORY: You've corrupted memory, hence the "malloc()" failure.
- LIKELY CANDIDATE: `fgets(tmpstr, CMDLENGTH-(strlen(delim)+1), cmdf);`

  <= You need to ensure that "n" (the second argument) is *NEVER* larger than  sizeof(tmpstr)-1.

It certainly *looks* like you're trying to do that ("n" should always be less than CMDLENGTH)... but it's worth double-checking.

SUGGESTION: try [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)

Comment: It's never larger because tmpstr is defined as `tmpstr[CMDLENGTH]` and `CMDLENGTH-(strlen(delim)+1)` is always at least `CMDLENGTH-1`

Comment: One would assume.  But I'd still be suspicious.  And as others have said, the corruption might have occurred *BEFORE* your function is called.  STRONG SUGGESTION: try Valgrind (or equivalent).  I'd also consider instrumenting 1) the value of each `block->command`, and 2) the vaue of each `CMDLENGTH-(strlen(delim)+1)`

Comment: Can Valgrind help if I can't reproduce the crash? It happens just from time to time, maybe like once in
a few days.